# How to find and replace string inside arrays in MongoDB and pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have a collection in MongoDB.(Technically it is the cosmosDB API for MongoDB but in theory that shouldn’t matter.) The collection contains nested arrays of strings.  These strings contain brackets inside them, and I need to remove them from the strings inside the arrays.  Sample (fake) data:

```
{
    “Thing_id”: “100”,
    “Thing_name”: “Thing100”
    “Comments”: [
        “Good: [Thing100 is awesome]”,
        “Bad: [I will never buy Thing100 again.]”
    ]
},
{
    “Thing_id”: “101”,
    “Thing_name”: “Thing101”
    “Comments”: [
        “Comparative: [Thing101 is so much better than Thing100.]”,
        “Bad: [Who designed such piece of …]”
    ]
}
]
```

Any above syntax errors are because I am typing it on my phone…my apologies if it is not well-formed json/bson.  To recap, I want to remove just the brackets in each value in the comments arrays. I am using pymongo to connect to the DB, and also python 3.7.4.

I have searched for how to do this, but all I can find are how to update the whole value in the array instead of replacing a character in the string inside the array.

FindAndModify() looked promising until I found out it will only do the first document found.

Is the only option to query the collection and loop through each document?

Comment: _"Technically it is the cosmosDB API for MongoDB but in theory that shouldn’t matter."_  Well, Azure Cosmos DB [_**"Fails 67% of compatibility tests."**_](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/compare).  Also see [Azure Cosmos DB feature support documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/feature-support-42).

Comment: What have you _tried_? This sounds like a relatively straightforward `update` using an aggregation pipeline and [string expression operators](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#string-expression-operators). I'm sure there are questions on this site about performing similar types of updates

Comment: @user20042973 Ironically I think I started down that path except without a valid pipeline…so I can’t really call it an attempt since I knew it wouldn’t work.  I went down multiple rabbit trails before ending up here.  So now that I know I was likely heading in the right direction in the beginning, I will look into it further. I will share my solution when I figure it out.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Thank you this is going to be extremely useful going forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have access to Azure Cosmos DB, so I can't test.  If you are using `pymongo` and want to update all documents in the collection, you probably want to use [`update_many`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_many).

Here are a couple parameters for `update_many` that may work for you.

```python
filter = {'$expr': {'$gt': [{'$size': '$Comments'}, 0]}}
update = [
  {
    "$set": {
      # rewrite Comments
      "Comments": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$Comments",
          "as": "comment",
          "in": {
            "$reduce": {
              "input": {
                # get all matches without "[" or "]"
                # every comment needs to be a string
                "$regexFindAll": {
                  "input": "$$comment",
                  # backslashes "\" are used to "escape" brackets
                  # the number of "\" required may depend on platform, etc.
                  "regex": "[^\\[\\]]*"
                }
              },
              "initialValue": "",
              "in": {
                # concat all matches
                "$concat": ["$$value", "$$this.match"]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

You can try this (slightly modified for the language/platform) on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZmRawz4POXm).

Comment: Nailed it! Thank you!

Comment: I should also mention that I didn't need to make any adjustments for CosmosDB.